# Angular App Not Communicating with API from Nginx Docker Container

Tags: angular, docker, rest, nginx, google-cloud-platform

I have a Java REST API in a docker container hosted with Google Cloud (on port 443).

I have an Angular web app which I can deploy on my local machine with `ng serve` that can communicate with the rest API as expected.

I am trying to dockerize the Angular app so I can deploy it on the cloud along with the API.  However, after I run the app with nginx inside a docker container, it displays the web page but can no longer communicate with the API.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:1.19.0-alpine
COPY /dist/app /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
EXPOSE 80
```

nginx.conf:

```
server {
    listen   80;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
}
```

Command to run Angular app:

```
Docker run -d -p 80:80 app
```

I'm not sure if I have to do something to specify to nginx or to Docker that the API is at [IP address] on port 443.

Edit: This is the only place the API url is mentioned in the Angular app:

```
export class ObjectService {

  private baseUrl = 'http://[ip address]:443/api-app/api/v1/objects';

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getObject(id: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/${id}`);
  }

...
```

Comment: What is the API URL at Angular web app config ? Are you sure that you have configured it correctly?

Comment: Edit: updated question with this information

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was the CrossOrigin settings on the API.  It was set to only accept requests from localhost:4200 which is where `ng serve` hosts by default.